# Filling html.textboxfor with value from another input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save a phone number, but when I try to pass in the value through some javascript, it is null in the backend.

this is my html

```
 <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { 
                id = "#phone",
                style = "display: none;",
            })
            <input type="tel" id="phoneInput" class="iti, form-control" />
        </div>
```

and this is my JS

```
document.getElementById("#phone").val("#phoneInput");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also get rid of the # in **id = "#phone"** as its not needed and will just complicate things as you learn more.

Then in getElementById don't need to pass the #. And second, **val** isn't valid vanilla javascript, and #phoneInput would just set the value to the string of "#phoneInput".

This is a very basic version of what you are trying

```
document.getElementById("phone").value = document.getElementById("phoneInput").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `#phone` as an `id`, just simply `phone` instead:

   `id = "phone"`
2. What is `.val()`?  You're trying to set the `.value` property:

   `document.getElementById("phone").value = "#phoneInput";`
3. Are you sure you want the value to be *the literal string* `"#phoneInput"`?  Or do you want it to be the value of the `phoneInput` element?:

   `document.getElementById("phone").value = document.getElementById("phoneInput").value;`
4. Make sure you do this *after* an actual value has been entered, such as in response to a `change` event or some other UI event.

```js
document.getElementById("phoneInput").addEventListener("change", function () {
  document.getElementById("phone").value = document.getElementById("phoneInput").value;
});
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
  <input type="tel" id="phoneInput" />
</div>
```

---

As an aside... Are you sure you need all of this at all?  Why not just make the `TextBoxFor` helper be a `tel` input?:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { type = "tel" })
```